# ForkJoinPool test fails on CI but not on local computer (after upgrade to junit 5 and spring 3)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gitlab

I have around 730 tests running fine after upgrading junit 4 to 5 and spring boot 2.x to 3.x. The following **test runs fine on my local computer** - both via intellij as well as via the exact same `./gradlew test ...` command as used in CI (see below).

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTest {
  // ...

  @InjectMocks
  private SomeComponent myComponent;
  @Test
  public void testOnNewAnswer_ExecutionException() {
    int batchSize = 10;
    AnswerCreatedEvent event = mock(AnswerCreatedEvent.class);
    SetupCalculation setup = mock(SetupCalculation.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    when(setup.getMatches().getNumberOfElements()).thenReturn(batchSize);
    AnswerDTOI answerDTO = mock(AnswerMC.class);
    when(answerDTO.getId()).thenReturn(13L);
    when(setup.getUs().getAnswer()).thenReturn(Optional.of(answerDTO));
    when(CalculationSetupFactory.setup(
            anyLong(),
            anyLong(),
            anyLong(),
            any(),
            any(),
            any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(setup));
    SomeCopmonent spy = spy(myComponent);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException("Simulated exception during calculation"))
            .when(calculator)
            .apply(2);
    doReturn(calculator).when(spy).createCalculator(any());

    /* unit under test*/
    spy.onNewAnswer(event);

    verify(calculator, times(batchSize)).apply(anyInt());
    // ... other verifications ...
  }
}
```

### On gitlab CI, however, it fails, because one iteration is missing:

and I don't have a clue how to fix it on CI?

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooFewActualInvocations: 
calculator.apply(<any integer>);
Wanted 10 times:
-> at com.mycompany.some.module.MyTest.testOnNewAnswer_ExecutionException(MyTest.java:190)
But was 9 times:
-> at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
-> at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
-> at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
-> at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
-> at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
-> at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
-> at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
-> at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
-> at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)

    at app//com.mycompany.some.module.MyTest.testOnNewAnswer_ExecutionException(MyTest.java:190)
    at java.base@17.0.8/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.8/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.8/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base@17.0.8/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.8/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.8/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

### This is the method under test:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SomeComponent {

  // ...

  private final static int BATCH_SIZE = 2500;

  private final static int PARALLELISM = Math.max(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2, 1);

  private ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(PARALLELISM);

  @PreDestroy
  public void shutdown() {
      forkJoinPool.shutdown();
  }

  @EventListener
  @Async("myExecutor")
  public void onNewAnswer(AnswerCreatedEvent event) {
    long t0 = Time.millis();
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, BATCH_SIZE);
    do {
        long t1 = Time.millis();
        Optional<SetupCalculation> sOpt = calculationSetupFactory.setup(...);
        if (sOpt.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        SetupCalculation setup = sOpt.get();
        List<Result> results = List.of();
        try {
            IntFunction<Result> calculator = createCalculator(setup);
            results = forkJoinPool.submit(
                    () -> IntStream.range(0, setup.getMatches().getNumberOfElements())
                            .parallel()
                            .mapToObj(calculator)
            ).get().collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Could not calculate updates", e);
        }
        // ... publish results via ApplicationEventPublisher ...
        pageable = setup.getMatches().nextPageable();
    } while (pageable.isPaged() /* returns false when behind the existing pages */);
  }
}
```

### The gitlab CI job:

```
backend_test:
  extends:
    - .backend
    - .backend_cache
  stage: test
  needs: []
  image: eclipse-temurin:17
  services:
    - postgres:13.1
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: foo
    POSTGRES_USER: foo
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: foo
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: ci
  script:
    - cd backend
    - ./gradlew clean test --stacktrace -i --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:+UseContainerSupport
    - cat build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: backend/build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml
    paths:
      - backend/build
    expire_in: 1 week
```

### Versions

- gradle `7.5.1`
- JDK

  - local machine `openjdk 17.0.7 2023-04-18`
  - CI: `eclipse-temurin:17` (docker image)
- spring boot `3.1.2`